# Will Anaconda work with Python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I'm a super newb, so forgive me if my question seems silly. I messed around a little bit with Python back in the day when Python 3.x didn't even exist, and I'm looking to do some web scraping, so I decided to re-familiarize myself with Python in order to use Scrapy. However, in the Scrapy documentation it suggests installing Anaconda, which I'm in the process of doing, but the only two downloads on the Anaconda website are: `Python 3.6 version *` and `Python 3.6 version *` (and I can't seem to find any information pertaining to `*`).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will:

you will have to wait for an iPython 3.7 distribution, and install it. In all likeliness, it will be published shortly after the python 3.7 final version, which is due around mid of June

Comment: What do you mean I'll have to wait for an iPython 3.7 distro? The last time I used Python was before the 3.x even existed :/

Comment: You will have to install iPython 3.7; in all likeliness, it will be published shortly after the python 3.7 final version, which is due around mid of June.

Comment: Is the `Anaconda 3.6 *` version compatible with `Python 3.6.5` because I wanna get to work ASAP?

Comment: Anaconda is a python distribution, plus some libraries, packaged together. The latest Anaconda 3.6, includes iPython 3.6.5

Comment: Ohhh, so I don't even need to install Python by itself. I didn't know it was bundled. Never even heard of this Anaconda program until now. Ty <3

Comment: Yes. In fact, if you read a little bit about the package manager `conda`, you will find that installing different versions of iPython in virtual environments is really easy, and make it a breeze to switch from one version to another, and/or use various sets of libraries.

Comment: Awesome! Can't wait to try it out now and eventually the 3.7 distro!

Comment: Is there any reason other than the ease of use to install Anaconda over Miniconda?!

Comment: IDK, I am using anaconda since before miniconda existed; I've never looked into it.

Comment: Strange. It's not letting me install Scrapy via the Anaconda Prompt (`conda install -c conda-forge scrapy`) invalid syntax?

Comment: Not every library is available through conda; some need to be installed via pip or pip3 - the anaconda website is a good resource to find which modules are available via the conda package manager.

Comment: Thanks. I looked in the `Environments` section and apparently only `beautifulsoup4` is there

Comment: @ReblochonMasque iPython (the package by the Jupyter group) != CPython (The standard Python interpreter), it seems like you're using them interchangeably, but they aren't the same thing

Comment: Yes, I agree, this is not explicitly emphasized in my answer, because it was not directly relevant to do so, but I am saying that iPython 3.7 will likely be published shortly after python 3.7: clearly I made a distinction between python and ipython, and did not loosely use the terms interchangeably.

Comment: The most recent version of iPython is 6.4, not 3.7. See: https://ipython.org/#announcements This is why I'm saying you're using them interchangeably. Perhaps iPython for Python 3.7? The OP never mentioned iPython in the question, but your first sentence is "you will have to wait for an iPython 3.7 distribution". Did you mean "CPython 3.7 distribution"?